# getting 17 low results from 70 in php

Tags: php, function, numbers, range

**Database table for try help me**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (
      `ticketid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `game` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `gameid` int(100) NOT NULL,
      `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `sum` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `numbers` varchar(27) NOT NULL,
      `count` int(2) NOT NULL,
      `how_much_win` int(20) NOT NULL,
      `win` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
      `checked` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
      PRIMARY KEY (`ticketid`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `tickets` (`ticketid`, `datetime`, `game`, `gameid`, `userid`, `sum`, `username`, `numbers`, `count`, `how_much_win`, `win`, `checked`) VALUES
(1, '2014-10-22 16:33:18', '1', 6592, 40294, 20, 'sergey', '13|19|31|49|50|61|65', 0, 0, 'no', 'no'),
(2, '2014-10-22 16:33:20', '1', 6592, 40294, 20, 'sergey', '8|10|36|38|44|50|68', 0, 0, 'no', 'no'),
(3, '2014-10-22 16:33:22', '1', 6592, 40294, 20, 'sergey', '2|14|31|42|48|56|64', 0, 0, 'no', 'no'),
(4, '2014-10-22 16:33:23', '1', 6592, 40294, 20, 'sergey', '8|11|26|34|37|42|44', 0, 0, 'no', 'no'),
(5, '2014-10-22 16:33:24', '1', 6592, 40294, 20, 'sergey', '5|27|28|55|60|62|67', 0, 0, 'no', 'no'),
(6, '2014-10-22 16:33:27', '2', 6592, 40294, 160, 'sergey', '1|15|19|25|38|47|62|64', 0, 0, 'no', 'no'),
(7, '2014-10-22 16:33:28', '2', 6592, 40294, 160, 'sergey', '2|6|40|45|54|56|69|70', 0, 0, 'no', 'no'),
(8, '2014-10-22 16:33:30', '3', 6592, 40294, 720, 'sergey', '1|7|23|47|54|55|57|59|68', 0, 0, 'no', 'no'),
(9, '2014-10-22 16:33:36', '3', 6592, 40294, 1080, 'sergey', '3|12|15|26|33|41|43|46|60', 0, 0, 'no', 'no'),
(10, '2014-10-22 16:33:45', '1', 6592, 40294, 30, 'sergey', '17|26|31|55|57|59|61', 0, 0, 'no', 'no');
```

**And here is page**

```
<?
$arr = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT numbers FROM tickets WHERE checked = 'no'") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($arr) > 0){
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($arr)) {
               foreach (explode("|", $res['numbers']) as $value) {
                        $numbers[$value]++;
               }    
       }

$numbers_f = array();
foreach ($numbers as $num => $value){
    $numbers_f[$num] += $value;
}
foreach (range(1, 70) as $num){
  echo 'Number '.$num.' = '.(isset($numbers_f[$num]) ? $numbers_f[$num] : '0').' times<br />';
}
}   
?>
```

This will show results on page like

```
Number 1 = 2 times
Number 2 = 2 times
Number 3 = 1 times
Number 4 = 0 times
Number 5 = 1 times
etc...
```

I need from all the list (70 number lines), create some function to **check** and **get the 17 low results**, (the low results = **number of times**. In here example the low results will be numbers with zero. But if i will be added more tickets, the low numbers can be zero with 1 or 1 with 2 etc.... And if you can help me with my question. I need more help, do (Most popular numbers) with high xx numbers.

Thanks for help! (and sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should dump all 70 entries in an array with the number as the key and the number of times as the value.

Then you sort it using [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) and you take the top xx or the bottom xx from your array using for example [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Comment: Good answer! Thanks. Can you help me dump the results. This line **echo 'Number '.$num.' = '.(isset($numbers_f[$num]) ? $numbers_f[$num] : '0').' times<br />';** .

Comment: @Misha You are already doing something almost exactly the same in the loop before that...